# How to create a link to Google Search using Product Name?

Tags: product, magento2.4

This might be a simple or difficult question, but I would like to create a button on my product pages that link to a search to online shopping. We don't sell online and I saw another website do that and thought it was great.  I copied their button code and I know where to put it but didn't know how to make the link a variable based on product name.

See Shop Online Button

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=REFLEX%20CARBON%20POLAR%20HELMET+REFLEX%20CARBON%20POLAR%20HELMET&amp;tbm=shop&amp;tbs=vw:g" class="info-grid-btn shop-online-btn">
                    SHOP ONLINE
                </a>
```

[image]

https://www.thormx.com/products/?productGroupId=419557&productId=592914

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to do, the difficulty depends on how experienced you are with your store theme and Magento 2. For example it can be achieved in any product template where you can get access to `$_product` i.e.

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<div>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=<?= $_product->getName() ?>" class="info-grid-btn shop-online-btn">
        <button type="button">SHOP ONLINE</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

If you do not have access to the backend of your store and are not familiar with your Magento 2 theme then it can also be easily implemented with a simple module.

Comment: I was going to use your code within a Magento content block within M2 admin but I guess it doesn't like PHP as it keeps commenting it out.  So I sent it over to the theme developers and hopefully they can give me advice on where to stick this thing.  thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Above was correct.  It works perfectly.  I had my theme developers add the button for me since I'm new to M2 (I know how the templates workin in M1 but still learning M2).  Thank you so much.